# Share DFS location and Change Name of DFS folders

Tags: domain-controller, network-share, dfs

I want to simplify file server access from displaying multiple drives to instead, share the DFS location that lists all of the shortcuts to the actual folders and files my users need access to. The reason being is we have MULTIPLE drives and it would be much easier to centralize all files and folders to one drive while using principle of least privilege.

I want to change some of the names of the folders in DFS to department names such as Accounting, Contact Center, etc. Can I change the name of the folder in DFS without having to create a new target??

For example:
Current: \domain\folder 1

Change to: \domain\Sales Department

Comment: Are you asking how to technically do it, or are you afraid that you might break things when you rename the folder? If you just want to rename the folder shortcut, go to DFS management, open your namespace, right-click on the folder, there you have an option to rename...

Comment: Yes I was hoping not to break anything when I rename the shortcut but I went ahead and did it anyway last naught because it’s only a shortcut. Renamed the shortcut but kept it pointed to the actual share and nothing broke. I just wanted to be extra careful and ask someone who may have more knowledge in this than I may have. It’s already done now so we’re good to go.